# warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)

Tags: visual-c++

This particular warning, generated on compiling my vc++ code in VS 2008 is bugging me for a while. On going through related posts in SO and in microsoft forums for this warning, It is advised to disable the warning using pragma warning, But is there a way to fix this issue without a warning pragma?

```
class CBLockException : public CBException
{
public:
    // Constructor
    CBLockException();
    CBLockException(const char *tag);
    CBLockException(const char *func, const char *tag, const char *msg = NULL);
};


class CLASS_DECL_BASEOBJECTS CBLock : public CBObject
{
public:

    enum Locktype { READLOCK, WRITELOCK };

    CBLock() throw (CBLockException*);   // C4290
    virtual ~CBLock();

    void Lock(Locktype lockType = WRITELOCK);
    void Unlock(Locktype lockType = WRITELOCK);

private:
    class LockImplementation;

    LockImplementation *lockImp;
};


class CBLock::LockImplementation
{

public:
    LockImplementation() throw (CBLockException*);  //C4290
    ~LockImplementation();

    CRITICAL_SECTION csExclusive;                      
    CRITICAL_SECTION csReader;                         
    HANDLE           hevReadDone;                        
    int              cReader;                               
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fix the issue"? MSVC doesn't fully implement the mandated semantics of exception specifications (which is what the warning is telling you). So if you want full semantics, you need to use a different compiler. If you want to keep using MSVC compiler, and you don't mind its non-conforming handling of exception specifications, then acknowledge that by disabling the warning. Either way, issue fixed.

Comment: Dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++, so the best solution would be to remove them from your code.

Answer (score 3):

> But is there a way to fix this issue without a warning pragma?

Yes. Delete the `throw` specification. It does not do what you think it does. Instead, it is mostly useless.

Specifically, writing:

```
CBLock() throw (CBLockException*);
…
CBLock::CBLock() { /* … */ }
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
CBLock();
…
CBLock::CBLock() {
    try {
        /* … */
    } catch(CBLockException*&) { // Yes, like this! Stop throwing exceptions by pointer, please!
        throw;
    } catch(...) {
        throw std::bad_exception();
    }
}
```

(actually, with constructor it will be equivalent to the function try block, but I don't want to complicate it further with yet another C++ wart)

In particular, notice it does *not* actually check that the block is not throwing any other kind of exception. The only thing it does is convert any other exception to a totally useless `std::bad_exception`, throwing any useful information away in the process.

The recommended fix is to convert any `throw` declarations to documentation comments!

Also note that this applies even to the `throw()` specification. The only useful thing is the `nothrow` specification introduced in C++11, which actually checks the function won't throw any C++ exception, ever, and it's earlier MSC++-specific `__declspec(nothrow)` equivalent.

Comment: No it is not useless. Only because Microsoft ignores the standard does not mean it is not necessary. SWIG for example uses it extensively as it is the only way to sure know if a function really throws an exception. The `#pragma warning(disable : 4290)` is the only right way.

Comment: @MichaelMaenz, the form with type list (which is what generates those warnings) was **removed altogether in C++17**. It is no longer valid C++ syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project Property Pages -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Disable Specific Warnings -> Edit

Enter codes of warnings to be disabled separated by semicolon (in your case 4290 without the leading "C")

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718.aspx